# Не запускается тест для springboot + javafx

Tags: spring, javafx, junit

При компиляции проекта https://github.com/ILDAR1976/transport_task.git столкнулся с такой проблемой. Когда запускаешь юнит-тестирование, закомментировав @Ignore аннотацию, получаю ошибку: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext. Не могу понять почему так происходить, ведь в при обычном запуске файл fxml загружался отлично, подымался spring контекст и все запускалось?

```
 package edu.transport_task;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Ignore;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

import edu.transport_task.service.ChargesPlaneService;

import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.annotation.DirtiesContext;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class)
public class ApplicationTests {



@Before
public void setUp() {

}

//@Ignore
@Test
    public void testDrawChargesPlane() {
    assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение:

```
package edu.transport_task;

import org.junit.BeforeClass;

...

@BeforeClass
Classpublic static void bootstrapJavaFx(){
    // implicitly initializes JavaFX Subsystem
    // see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14025718/javafx-toolkit-not-initialized-when-trying-to-play-an-mp3-file-through-mediap
    new JFXPanel();
}
```

Спасибо, ruslanys/sample-spring-boot-javafx